# Spring WebFlux Functional Endpoint throwing 404 instead of 415 for invalid media type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

We are using Spring Boot 2 (v2.0.1.RELEASE) functional endpoints. We have an endpoint like this:

```
private RequestPredicate getByIdPredicate() {
  return RequestPredicates.GET("/*/{id}").and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
}
```

While invoking the API with a wrong media type (e.g. `application/invalidMediaType`), the endpoint is throwing `404`. I understand this behavior (both predicates did not match). However, I want this to throw `415 Unsupported media type`. How to achieve this?

Comment: If you're using the functional interface rather than annotations, it looks like you have to explicitly define that behavior yourself. Seems crazy and unpleasant, but the docs and api documentation don't seem to show a good way to do this.

Comment: I agree, I could see they have coded the exception in `RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping#handleNoMatch` method, but but that part of code never executes.

Comment: Anybody from Spring WebFlux team? Can you guys give some pointer? I was thinking if there's a way I can access to some kind of registry you might be maintaining for this mapping (between `RequestPredicate` and corresponding Handler)?

Answer (score 0):

With Spring WebFlux fn, `RouterFunction` is here to give you full control about request mapping; the same way, the handler contract is very general (takes a `ServerRequest`, returns a `Mono<ServerResponse>`).

Everything is designed to give you full control; this comes with a cost as things need to be a bit more explicit. In your case, content negotiation is not done for you and you need to express that in `RequestPredicates` or manage that behavior at the handler level.

In your case, I can see a couple of ways to deal with it:

- you can `RequestPredicate.nest()` predicates; for example, nest a global path predicate for `"/api/*"` endpoints and have under this an `accept` predicate that checks for the right media type (and then nest other predicates under it), and use a specific handler that returns HTTP 415 for all others
- you can make that check directly in handlers by checking the `ServerRequest` and return HTTP 415 from there

There is no hard rule about this, and WebFlux *functional* doesn't provide a registry for that for a good reason: a `RouterFunction` is just a function and it's good practice to avoid shared state and mutability.

Comment: Brian, I agree to all your points; but help me understand this - the `RouterFunction` bean that I configure (with all routes n their handlers) are scanned only once during bootstrapping (I checked by debugging the code). So, unless WebFulx stores a mapping (RouterFunction to Handler) how does it invoke the handler for every call? By registry I meant that mapping. I want to implement such a validation at a common place (an aspect or a Filter) instead of every handler and I am looking for such a mapping registry.

Comment: Is it possible to have an example?